# Bug of the function ConvexHullRegion

Tags: regions

The function `ConvexHullRegion` give the following bug (Mathematica 12.2)

```
R = ConvexHullRegion[{{4, 0}, {3, 1}, {2, 2}, {1, 3}, {0, 4}}];

RegionMember[R, {3, 1}]

(* False *)
```

whereas `{3,1}` belongs to `R`

Comment: Report this to [`Wolfram Tech Support`](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=feedback).

Comment: I’m voting to close this post because it is a bug report, not a question. To ensure that Wolfram Research is notified of bugs, talk to them directly.

Comment: @ErcoleSuppa It's great that you found this bug. But notice that this is not an official site by Wolfram Research, so we cannot do anything about this. So please do as suggested by Bob Hanlon and Szabolcs and report it to Wolfram Tech Support.